# Error in running react native android app from shell

Tags: android, react-native

When I run react-native run-android in my terminal my app crushes and I get an error in Logcat

> 12-21 18:02:01.358 23136-23136/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main
>       Process: com.munasabat, PID: 23136
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.munasabat.MainApplication: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class
>   com.munasabat.MainApplication is not accessible from class
>   android.app.Instrumentation
>           at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:625)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5082)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:177)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1509)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5938)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class com.munasabat.MainApplication is not accessible from class
>   android.app.Instrumentation
>           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1635)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1003)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:988)
>           at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:620)

But if I run the app using Android Studio, it runs fine.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: I did added the stack trace now, have a look, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "public" to your Application constructor:

from "class MainApplication extends Application..."

to "**public** class MainApplication extends Application..."